# Can I assume the sender is the original actor on eventStream.subscribe

Tags: scala, akka

When I subscribe for published events on the event stream:

```
actor.subscribe(self, classOf[MyEvent])
```

and receive a publihed event:

```
case _: MyEvent =>
  val realSender = sender // ???
```

Is it safe to assume the sender is always the actor that published the event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it safe to assume the sender is always the actor that published the event?

No. From the [documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/event-bus.html#event-bus):

> Please note that the EventBus does not preserve the sender of the published messages. If you need a reference to the original sender you have to provide it inside the message.